# Is it possible to automatically update a dockerized app when i make push to the repository?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

I have a dockerized app running on a Digital Ocean server, the way i am updating my app is, pushing the local changes to my repo, and after it, i go to my Digital Ocean server through SSH and pull new my changes. Finally through some "make" commands i rebuild my image and restart my containers if necessary, there is a known way to automate this? i'm new on CI/CD stuffs. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this what CD is for. I.e. check my article here - https://itnext.io/building-kubernetes-cicd-pipeline-with-github-actions-argocd-and-reliza-hub-e7120b9be870

Comment: just reading @taleodor thanks!

Comment: No problem, if you have quick questions as you go we also have discord group here - https://discord.gg/UTxjBf9juQ